# how can I print the for loop HashMap result once?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

This is a method to print out the fee records for a particular member but it keeps on printing out the result as many as the number of members.

```
public void printFeeRecords(String anID)
{
    Member aMembers = findMemberByID(anID);


    for( Member aMember : members){

        System.out.println(aMembers.getFeeRecords());

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you found `aMembers` using `findMemberByID(anID)`, why don't you just print the fees instead of looping through every member?

Comment: I have got no idea. I did it without a loop and the professor told me that i'm halfway there and said that it involves a loop.

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a talk with your professor to clarify what the requirements are for this assignment.

Comment: Then you need to use a loop in order to compare every ID with the input ID and if you find a match, then you print.

Answer (score 1):

You already found the correct member - you don't need to iterate the others:

```
public void printFeeRecords(String anID)
{
    Member aMembers = findMemberByID(anID);
    System.out.println(aMembers.getFeeRecords());
}
```

Comment: See, that's the sort of thing that you need to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

By writing:

```
1. for( Member aMember : members) {
2.    System.out.println(aMembers.getFeeRecords());
3. }
```

What you're saying is:

1. For each thing in `members`, bind that thing to the variable `aMember`, and do line 2
2. Take the thing bound to `aMembers`, and call its `getFeeRecords()` method, and print the result

So while we're using the correct member (`aMembers` - with an 's', not `aMember`, the loop variable), we're still going to do the thing once for each thing in `members`.

Note that if the loop was `for( Member aMembers : members)...` we would be printing the fee record *for each thing in `members`* i.e. the original value of `aMembers` set beforehand from `findMemberByID()` would be overwritten while we were in the loop. After the loop ends, though, we would still have it. This is related to a concept called *scope*

Comment: If you *really* want a `for` loop solution, I would suggest the following: For each member in `members`, check whether the ID is equal to the one you're looking for, and if it is, print that member's fee records, if not keep looking. Your solution without a loop *is better* - it saves you a lot of time to just get the member without iterating through the whole collection, but if your professor demands a loop, you can give them one

Answer (score 0):

You practically ask if the current member has the id provided in the parameter - anID.

```
   public void printFeeRecords(String anID) {

        for( Member aMember : members) {

            if (aMember.getId() == anId) {

                System.out.println(aMembers.getFeeRecords());
            }
        }
    }
```